# C# Most secure way to load a password into Process method with a service

Tags: c#, service, password-storage

I have a C# service that needs to run a process as another user (interactive mode). That user is an admin level user and I know I should NOT store the password as a string in the code.

I could use some help pointing me in the right direction as all the research I have done seems point to a ton of methods that all do not seem to fit with what I want to do.

Am I required to store a hashed PW in a config file? Can I store a hashed PW right in the code and someone pass that to a secure string? I feel a bit lost here and could use some guidance.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to save the PW as a SecureString - but you should directly parse the PW in its original form to a SecureString and not save it as a normal string - not even in your code as a global variable. Parsing to a SecureString shouldn't be difficult though.

Comment: Problem is I am not plugging the PW in. I need the service to do this for me on a schedule.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, you need the plaintext password, so you can start the external process as another user. This would rule out password hashes, since you need the plaintext password.

1) Probably the safest thing you can do, is to ask for the password whenever the service starts. The service can then hold the password in memory as long as the service is up.

- This way you don't have to store the password at all on the harddisk.
- The disadvantage is of course that the password must be entered when the service starts.

2) If you need to persist the password, there is no absolute safe way, but Windows offers an Api for exactly this problem, the Data Protection API (DPAPI). It solves the problem, that one cannot encrypt a password, without storing the key somewhere (which raises the question of where to store the key...).

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintextPassword);
byte[] encryptedPassword = ProtectedData.Protect(passwordBytes, optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
```

With this code, Windows will encrypt the password using information of the running computer. Only your process running on this computer should be able to decrypt the password then.